# Hibernate @CreationTimestamp @UpdateTimestamp in different time zones

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

Using below two for storing updation and creation time.

```
@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp creationTime;

@UpdateTimestamp
private Timestamp updationTime;
```

When I create a new record both of these are stored in the `UTC` timezone.

```
+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| meeting_id | analysis_description             | meeting_date | preread_date | first_version_date | reminder_sent_date | review_addressed_date | review_comments_addressed | tfls | first_record_flag | current_record_flag | created_by | updated_by | creation_time       | updation_time       | end_time |
+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|          4 | BAF312A2122 - CRT 1 - LEGACY CRT | NULL         | NULL         | NULL               | NULL               | NULL                  | NULL                      |    0 | Y                 | Y                   | NULL       | NULL       | 2019-10-04 06:36:36 | 2019-10-04 06:36:36 | NULL     |
+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However if I update the record, the creation timestamp changes to my localtimestamp.

```
+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| meeting_id | analysis_description             | meeting_date | preread_date | first_version_date | reminder_sent_date | review_addressed_date | review_comments_addressed | tfls | first_record_flag | current_record_flag | created_by | updated_by | creation_time       | updation_time       | end_time |
+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|          4 | BAF312A2122 - CRT 1 - LEGACY CRT | 2019-09-30   | 2019-09-30   | 2019-09-30         | 2019-09-30         | 2019-09-30            | yes                       |    1 | Y                 | Y                   | NULL       | NULL       | 2019-10-04 12:08:20 | 2019-10-04 06:38:20 | NULL     |
+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also both get updated instead of just the updation Time.

I tried various config changes but they are all behaving the same.

1. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`
2. Using post construct

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class IdotApplication {

   @PostConstruct
   void started() {
       TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(IdotApplication.class, args);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Date instead of timezone

   @CreationTimestamp
   private Date creationTime;
4. @CreationTimestamp
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date creationTime;
5. @Column(updatable=false)
   @CreationTimestamp
   private Date creationTime;

also `serverTimezone=UTC` is already defined in connection along with `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rmcdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused due the a feature of mysql, I am using `mysql 5.7+`, `liquibase` with raw sql for schema generation.

If I create a column in mysql with `timestamp` it deafaults to auto updation.

```
mysql> create table test ( a timestamp );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe test;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| a     | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

When the new record was created both timestamps were in `UTC` timezone since `hibernate` was overiding mysql.

But when the record is updated `on update current_timestamp` from `mysql` fires while `hibernate` doesn't do anything since it's `@creationTimeStamp`  hence it remains in the localtimezone which `mysql` has put.

To resolve, I defined the field as

```
creation_time timestamp null,
updation_time timestamp null
```

Now `mysql` doesn't interfere, updation etc. all are done through hibernate only.

If you find explanation bit confusing and are using `mysql` go over below article that would clarify. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Hope it helps somebody.